# How to close an instance of itself in java

Tags: java, oop, instance

I've been messing around with some ideas for a mini project I will have to do for university in the coming months in which I will have to create an ATM program and I've hit an obstacle was just wondering if anyone could help. In my main class I create an instance of a JFrame form called EnterPin:

```
public class Main {   
    public static void main(String args[]){
        EnteringPin EnterPin = new EnteringPin();
        EnterPin.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This creates a window for a user to enter their pin and when the enter button is pressed and the pin is correct (I have an array containing pins) it opens up another JFrame form of an ATM main screen. I wanted to know how to close the instance "EnterPin" from within itself as I cant just do EnterPin.dispose(); like I'm used to. I've tried creating a boolean within EnterPin called "open" and changing it to true when the main screen window opens, so that I can use a while loop in the main:

```
public class Main {  
    public static void main(String args[]){
        EnteringPin EnterPin = new EnteringPin();
        EnterPin.setVisible(true);
        while (EnterPin.open == false){
        }
        EnterPin.dispose();
    }
}
```

This works when I put a breakpoint at the while loop and debug this program but when I simply run it the EnterPin instance stays up in the background.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `JFrame` use `JDialog` with `modalityType` set to `APPLICATION_MODAL`. When shown, it will block the thread that opened it until it is closed. Store any result data inside the class itself.

```
public class EnteringPin extends JDialog {
    // ...
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    EnteringPin EnterPin = new EnteringPin();
    EnterPin.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    EnterPin.setVisible(true);

    DataType data = EnterPin.data; // Get data
    // ...
}
```

Within the `EnteringPin`, register a `WindowAdapter` on the `onWindowClosed` and dispose, etc. from there.